# Cannot read property 'children' of undefined error message

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, undefined, children

Im pretty new to Javascript and i have successfully connected my XML-file to my Javascript-file through AJAX. It's not important at the moment because now I am wondering about this code down below which gives me the error **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined"** in the console.

I am trying to get the source of the first child of **images** which is an image in my XML-file, and print it in my div with the id="single-pic" . Is there a syntax error here?

Why is this?

```
function parseXML(counter) {
 var xml = ajax.responseXML;
 var images = xml.getElementsByTagName("imageinfo");
 console.log(images[0]);
 document.getElementById('single-pic').innerHTML = "<img src='" + images[counter].children[0].getAttribute('src') + "'/>";
}
```

Comment: It means that `images[counter]` is `undefined`. What is the value of `counter`?

Comment: You have to check that `counter` belong to `images`'s indices before accessing `images[counter]`

Comment: counter is declared outside and is set to 0. Im using it in another function to increase and decrease it's value by pressing left and right key. If i type console.log(counter); it's printing out a number.

Comment: can you print the value of images[counter].children[0].getAttribute('src') on console and see if you get an error ?

Comment: It prints the number 0 and then the source of the picture location "/uploads/picture.jpeg".